# How repeat part of function Swift

Tags: ios, swift, repeat

still learning the basics. I have a function in which there is a block, that needs to be repeated without calling the whole function again. How is this done in Swift?

```
func connected(to peripheral: Peripheral) {
    let cwConnection = CWStatusBarNotification()
    cwConnection.display(withMessage: "Ring Connected", forDuration: 3)

    BluejayManager.shared.getHeliosInfo { (success) in
        if success {
            // Go on
        } else {
            // Repeat this block (BluejayManager.shared.getHeliosInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Riyan it's just simple. Here is the solution to your problem. Just put the block in other small method and when you just need to call that block call that small function.

```
func connected(to peripheral: Peripheral) {
    let cwConnection = CWStatusBarNotification()
    cwConnection.display(withMessage: "Ring Connected", forDuration: 3)

    self.callBluejayManagerShared() // Call of block from method
}

func callBluejayManagerShared(){
    BluejayManager.shared.getHeliosInfo { (success) in
        if success {
            // Go on
        } else {
            // Repeat this block (BluejayManager.shared.getHeliosInfo)
            self.callBluejayManagerShared()
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you just want to call block you just need to call `self.callBluejayManagerShared()` method.
Hope this help you

Comment: A recursive solution like this is not desirable. Sooner or later, it'll cause a stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

You can use `repeat - while` around and `BluejayManager.shared.getHeliosInfo` check for `success` as break condition:

```
repeatGetInfo: repeat {
    BluejayManager.shared.getHeliosInfo 
    { (success) in
            if success 
            {
                // do your stuff.
                break repeatGetInfo
            } else 
            {
                continue repeatGetInfo
            }
        }
} while true
```

Hope this helps